# trying to get the number of letters in a str

Tags: python

So i'm just doing a little function that takes prompts a user for a word and a letter and the function should return the number of occurences of that letter in the word that was given.

so for example, what i want my function to do is this:

```
please enter a word: 'hello'
please enter a letter: 'l'
2
```

my code is the following:

```
def num_char():
    char = input('please enter a word: ')
    char_to_find = input('please enter a letter: ')
    num = 0    
    for i in char:
        if i == char_to_find:
            num += 1
    return num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_char()
```

the thing is that when i run this, it only prompts the user but doesn't do anything afterwards. Any ideas on what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Works on my computer.

Comment: While this may not help you if you're doing a homework assignment, in production code you'll probably want to use `str.count` rather than doing this with a manual loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually printing anything. `print` your `returned` value

```
def num_char():
    char = input('please enter a word: ')
    char_to_find = input('please enter a letter: ')
    num = 0    
    for i in char:
        if i == char_to_find:
            num += 1
    return num

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print num_char()  #for python-2.7
    print(num_char()) #for python-3.x
```

Comment: Your 2nd idea seems more pythonic -- if the code were invoked as a module, you'd probably want the return value....

Comment: thanks it actually returns something now. Unfortunately it only returns 0..any reason why?

Comment: @user3050527, Try casting your input as `str` as `str(input('please enter a word: '))` and for the other one as well

Comment: oh wow.. why i had to use the str function? if the user inputs a str, then shouldn't it iterate over the str? sorry im new to this..

Comment: @user3050527, actually `raw_input()` in `python-2.7` did that. In `python-3.x`, input can also be an expression so you have to tell the interpreter what to interpret it as. Hope that helped

Comment: @user3050527, Also when you input something, don't type it as `"hello"`, just type `hello`. Good Luck